# parse html file, obtaining data from nested categories hierarchy using xslt 3

Tags: xslt-3.0

given the following html file:

http://bpeck.com/references/DDC/ddc_mine900.htm

http://bpeck.com/references/DDC/ddc_mine200.htm

http://bpeck.com/references/DDC/ddc_mine500.htm

etc,

how i could get an output that would show me the hierarchy of the categories?

```
/---------------------
| ID  | Name
| 1   | Main Category
| 3   |   Sub Category
| 5   |     Sub-Sub Category
| 4   |   Sub Category
| 2   | Next Main Category
\----------------------
```

Ideally if the output result could be in json format, but i guess xml could do.

Struggled with a serial parser (SAX), but failed, looking for an elegant solution.

main categories

```
    900 World History

    910 Geography and travel [see area subdivisions]

    920 Biography, genealogy, insignia

    930 History of the ancient world

    940 General history of Europe [check schedules for date subdivisions]

    950 General history of Asia, Far East
```

etc...

subcategories of 900:

```
900 Geography & history
901 Philosophy & theory
902 Miscellany
903 Dictionaries & encyclopedias
904 Collected accounts of events
905 Serial publications
906 Organizations & management
907 Education, research, related topics
908 With respect to kinds of persons
```

...

example of a sub sub category found under 909 World history:

```
909.7 18th century, 1700-1799
909.8 1800-
909.82 1900-
```

output i would prefer the best approach you judge would be the best.
each key would be the ID, which is 900, 901, 902, etc, and the corresponding value would be the name:  Geography & history, Philosophy & theory, Miscellany. This output json should be nested, showing the hierarchy of the categories.
I use saxon HE version 9.8

Comment: The result you have shown doesn't show any sample data, nor it is XML or JSON. So where do you get the `ID` values from, what do you consider a main category, a sub category, and so on?

Comment: And which XSLT 3 processor do you use as the input is not XML but HTML? Do you use Saxon PE or EE where you have http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/parse-html.html or some other way to plug in an HTML parser into the tool chain?

Comment: i use saxon HE 9.8.

Comment: It depends, do you use the Java version of Saxon HE? How do you run it, from the command line, from Java code? Can you install TagSoup http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/? Saxon (even HE) has a command line option `-x` to name a parser so if TagSoup is on the class path then `-x:org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser` is supposed to use that parser for the input instead of a normal XML parser, then you have the (X)HTML tree TagSoup gives as the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you have seems poorly structured (only checked http://bpeck.com/references/DDC/ddc_mine900.htm but that doesn't pass HTML validation at https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbpeck.com%2Freferences%2FDDC%2Fddc_mine900.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0, in particular the lists of subcategories are not properly nested so some XSLT plumbing is needed).

As for parsing HTML with XSLT 2 or 3, if you can't set up Saxon to use an HTML parser like TagSoup instead of an XML parser for the input you can try to use David Carlisle's `htmlparse` function implemented in pure XSLT 2, it is available online at https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/blob/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl, make sure you download a local copy if you want to use it to parse your HTML in XSLT 2 or 3 with good performance.

Here is an example that uses the online copy and parses the input HTML into some XML format I made up:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:d="data:,dpc"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

    <xsl:param name="html-file" as="xs:string">http://bpeck.com/references/DDC/ddc_mine900.htm</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="html-text" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text($html-file)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="html-doc" select="d:htmlparse($html-text, '', true())"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <categories>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tail($html-doc//table)"/>
        </categories>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <category>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:create-attributes(tr[1]/td[1])"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="head(tr)/td[2], tail(tr)/td[1]"/>
        </category>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td">
        <subcategory>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:create-attributes(.)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::td[1]/ul"/>
        </subcategory>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="li">
            <sub-sub-category>
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:create-attributes(.)"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>
            </sub-sub-category>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="mf:create-attributes" as="attribute()*">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="input-components" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(normalize-space($input))"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="head($input-components)"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="title" select="tail($input-components)"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBud

To create JSON with XSLT 3, you have a couple of options, one is to have your stylesheet create the format the `xml-to-json` function expects (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json-to-xml-mapping); in the following example I extend the above stylesheet with a mode that takes the previous result XML to create the XML input you can feed to `xml-to-json`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:d="data:,dpc"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

    <xsl:param name="html-file" as="xs:string">http://bpeck.com/references/DDC/ddc_mine900.htm</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="html-text" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text($html-file)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="html-doc" select="d:htmlparse($html-text, '', true())"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="categories">
            <categories>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tail($html-doc//table)"/>
            </categories>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$categories" mode="json"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <category>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:create-attributes(tr[1]/td[1])"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="head(tr)/td[2], tail(tr)/td[1]"/>
        </category>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td">
        <subcategory>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:create-attributes(.)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::td[1]/ul"/>
        </subcategory>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="li">
            <sub-sub-category>
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:create-attributes(.)"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>
            </sub-sub-category>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="mf:create-attributes" as="attribute()*">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="input-components" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(normalize-space($input))"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="head($input-components)"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="title" select="tail($input-components)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:mode name="json" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <xsl:template match="category | subcategory | sub-sub-category" mode="json">
        <fn:map>
            <fn:map key="{@name}">
                <fn:string key="title">{@title}</fn:string>
                <xsl:where-populated>
                    <fn:array key="children">
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
                    </fn:array>
                </xsl:where-populated>
            </fn:map>
        </fn:map>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBud/1

The final step then would to use the function `xml-to-json` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-xml-to-json) to output JSON instead of XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:d="data:,dpc"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

    <xsl:param name="html-file" as="xs:string">http://bpeck.com/references/DDC/ddc_mine900.htm</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="html-text" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text($html-file)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="html-doc" select="d:htmlparse($html-text, '', true())"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="categories">
            <categories>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tail($html-doc//table)"/>
            </categories>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$categories" mode="json"/>            
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <category>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:create-attributes(tr[1]/td[1])"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="head(tr)/td[2], tail(tr)/td[1]"/>
        </category>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td">
        <subcategory>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:create-attributes(.)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::td[1]/ul"/>
        </subcategory>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="li">
            <sub-sub-category>
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:create-attributes(.)"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>
            </sub-sub-category>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="mf:create-attributes" as="attribute()*">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="input-components" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(normalize-space($input))"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="head($input-components)"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="title" select="tail($input-components)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:mode name="json" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <xsl:template match="category | subcategory | sub-sub-category" mode="json">
        <fn:map>
            <fn:map key="{@name}">
                <fn:string key="title">{@title}</fn:string>
                <xsl:where-populated>
                    <fn:array key="children">
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
                    </fn:array>
                </xsl:where-populated>
            </fn:map>
        </fn:map>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBud/2

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBud/3 is the same code applied to a different input file, at least the XML -> XML -> JSON generation doesn't break, I haven't checked whether the HTML table and lists are having the same structure as in the previous input.

As another option to create JSON with XSLT 3 and support for XPath 3.1 map and array data types (which both Saxon 9.8/9.9 in all editions provide as well as Altova 2017/2018/2019) you can directly create maps and arrays and serialize with method `json`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:d="data:,dpc"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

    <xsl:param name="html-file" as="xs:string"
        >http://bpeck.com/references/DDC/ddc_mine900.htm</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="html-text" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text($html-file)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="html-doc" select="d:htmlparse($html-text, '', true())"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tail($html-doc//table)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:category-map(tr[1]/td[1], (head(tr)/td[2], tail(tr)/td[1]))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td">
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:category-map(., following-sibling::td[1]/ul)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="li">
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:category-map(., tail(current-group()))"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="mf:split-index-title" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:sequence
            select="
                let $components := tokenize(normalize-space($input))
                return
                    (head($components), string-join(tail($components), ' '))"
        />
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:category-map" as="map(xs:string, item())">
        <xsl:param name="category" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:param name="subcategories" as="element()*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="components" select="mf:split-index-title($category)"/>
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="$components[1]">
                <xsl:map>
                    <xsl:map-entry key="'title'" select="$components[2]"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$subcategories">
                        <xsl:map-entry key="'children'">
                            <xsl:sequence select="array{ mf:child-categories($subcategories) }"/>
                        </xsl:map-entry>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:map>
            </xsl:map-entry>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:child-categories" as="map(xs:string, item())*">
        <xsl:param name="subcategories" as="element()*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$subcategories"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBud/4